# Parameters in Child Routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular4-router

In my Angular 4 application I have a routing like:

`ticketBundles/:code/copy` and `ticketBundles/:code`

How can I route to this specific view and how can I retrieve the correct code?
the 2 pages are different so I need to load different modules.

I have a routes like this:

```
export const TicketBundleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TicketBundleListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: TicketBundleNewComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':code',
    component: TicketBundleDetailComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'copy',
        component: TicketBundleNewComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

How can I route to the children component?

I know about query params 
`this.router.navigate(['/ticketBundle', this.code , {action: 'copy'}]);`
but I don't want a path formatted like: 
`/ticketBundle/1;action=copy`

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you meant not different modules but different components.

```
 [
      {
        path: 'ticketBundles/:code',
        component: TicketComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'copy',
            component: SomeOtherComponent
          }
        ]
      }

]
```

Comment: I udated the question